# Access return value in my class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have a class located in my app_code folder named

myClass.cs

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER", HttpContext.Current.Session["MYUSER"]);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@STATUS", SqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters["@STATUS"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


try
{
     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     int status = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@STATUS"].Value);
     return Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["userStatus"] = status);
}
catch...
```

I am adding the result to a session variable here but not sure if this is the most efficient way to approach this. Is there a way I could access the return value on the client side code without creating a session?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden field or the `ViewState`.  A hidden field would probably be better to use since you can retrieve the value easily via JavaScript.

In the markup you should have the field:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hiddenFieldId" runat="server" />
```

You can assign the field via:

```
hiddenFieldId.Value = status.ToString();
```

Then to access via JavaScript:

```
var hiddenFieldValue = document.getElementById('<%=hiddenFieldId.ClientID %>').value
```